# C++ subscript [] operator overloading

Tags: c++, indexing, overloading, operator-keyword, subscribe

Sorry for the format, I never really posted to a forum like this, so I have to learn the how to a bit.

My problem is:
I'm writing a template class, and I'd like to access my containers via multiple kind of `[]` operators. I read a bit in this subject, so I've been able to make one overloading, but I need some more:

So in my header file, relevant things about my container:

```
template <class T>
class version_controlled_vector
{
    int rev;                                         
    bool vector_state_changed;
    std::vector< std::string > revision;     
    std::vector< std::vector<T> > v;                 


    //first one works ok, im satisfied with it:
    std::vector<T>& operator[] (const int idx)
    {
        return v[idx];
    }

    //im not sure how to define the further one(s?):
    T& operator[](const int idx2) const
    {
        return v[idx2];
    }
    //...and ofc some other code
};
```

//to have these usages at my main.cpp:

```
version_controlled_vector<int> mi;
version_controlled_vector<std::string> ms;

//this works, and i d like to keep it,
5 == mi[ 0 ][ 0 ];

//and i d like to have these two usages too:
//getting the first character of the stored string:

'H' == ms[ 0 ][ 0 ];    // with the first overload from the header ms[0][0][0]    
works  to get the first character of the string for eg "Hello" 
but, i have to use  the ms[0][0] format to achieve this

//and this:
4 == mi[ 0 ]; // i d like this as if it d behave like 4 == mi[0][0];
```

I don't really get how can I use the `single[]` when I made an overload to use the `[][]`

The only solution I have read about is maybe const-overloading, but I'm not sure at all, I'm quite a weakie.

Thanks for ideas!

Comment: First off, welcome to StackOverflow (Not a forum, but a Q&A site). Now, going to the basics: What do you mean by "version-controlled vector? Does it mean your class must start a new revision whenever the content of the container changes? Because then you are definitely exposing the internal vector too much. (Which btw. already has a subscript operator) Related reading: [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Comment: I don't understand what you are after.  You want `mi[0]` to be an `int`, but `mi[0][0]` to also be an `int`?

Comment: Your intention for overloading `operator[]` is not clear at all. And what part does `revision` play in any of this? If none, why is it even in your sample?

Comment: Vaughn Cato: yes, i d like to access mi[0][0] with the syntax mi[0], so to an int.
WhozCraig: yes revision is not really relevant part here. This program is practising, and its my first post, so i made this mistake, at least leared from it :)
Basically its a container, where i can store data of different versions in separate vectors. revision vector can contain a comment for each version. main is made by someone else, and i have to implement the header. to say the truth goal of single [] is a bit unclear for me, especially if we have [][] to access everyting. anyway thanks for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are muddying the interface of the class. The expectations from the class are:

1. Get the i-th value from the j-th version.
2. Get the i-th value from the latest version.
3. Get the j-th version.

You have the option of using the overloaded `operator[]` function to get those values but, it will be better to have functions that reflect the interface.

```
// Get the versionIndex-th version.
std::vector<T>& getVersion(int versionIndex);

// Get the itemIndex-th value from the versionIndex-th version.
T& getItem(int versionIndex, int itemIndex);

// Get the itemIndex-th value from the latest version.
T& getItem(int itemIndex);
```

Then, the implementation would be simpler and less confusing.

```
std::vector<T>& getVersion(int versionIndex)
{
    // Make sure to add out of bound checks
   return v[versinIndex];
}

T& getItem(int versionIndex, int itemIndex)
{
    // Make sure to add out of bound checks
   return v[versinIndex][itemIndex];
}

T& getItem(int itemIndex);
{
    // Make sure to add out of bound checks
   return v.back()[itemIndex];
}
```

Given these, the only `operator[]` that makes sense, at least to me, is one that returns the i-th value from the latest version.

```
T& operator[](int itemIndex);
{
    // Make sure to add out of bound checks
   return v.back()[itemIndex];
}
```

Comment: Why not use a magic proxy? It can just work for this case, unless `T` has a subscript operator...

Comment: @Deduplicator, please elaborate what you mean by "magic proxy".

Comment: Letting the subscript return a class which can be implicitly converted to `T`, as well as providing a subscript operator for the second level.

Comment: @Deduplicator, I looked for a way to do that, but I didn't find a simple way.

Comment: @captain_stack, The outcome of `ms[0][0]` depends on the what `ms[0]` evaluates to. If you are happy with `ms[0]` returning the 0-th item of the latest `std::vector<std::string>`, then, the function I have in the answer is good.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky one, you need to realise that when you write

```
version_controlled_vector<int> mi;
5 == mi[0][0];
```

during the second fetch you're no longer accessing your `version_controlled_vector` class but the inner property of it and it's type is `std::vector<T>` which has its own subscript operator that you call in the second `[0]`.

To control the subscript operator of the second fetch you need to create another class that derives from `std::vector<T>` and has overloaded subscript operator. Then you should use this class instead of the `std::vector` in the implementation of `version_controlled_vector`.